# Excel formula to set "one month/year" before?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have to create a dataset with intervals (month and year).

Does it exist a formula that give me the same day but 1 month/year before?

I know I can use

> =today()-30

or

> =today()-365

but not all month are by 30 days (and the same for years).

I know I can use =day() to extract the day then compose it with the =month()-1 and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For month you can use [`EDATE` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/EDATE-function-3c920eb2-6e66-44e7-a1f5-753ae47ee4f5?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1):
`=EDATE(TODAY,-1)`

For years you need to use more complex functions:
`=DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1,MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY()))`

Comment: These formulas work. The tricky part with the month is making sure that Mar 31 - 1 month = Feb 29. EDATE() handles that, no problem.